# Есть возможность обработать нажатия на кнопки Toolbar в отдельном классе, не в активности?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Хочу сделать некий отдельный класс - Менеджер Панели.
При создании активности создается объект этого класса, который на Toolbar-е активности выводит какие-то кнопки.

Хочется, чтобы нажатия на эти кнопки обрабатывались в самом объекте, а не в активности.

Можно как-то перекрыть метод активности onOptionsItemSelected или как-то еще обработать нажатия?

Или я слишком много хочу и нужно по другому делать?

Comment: м.б попробовать mvp

Comment: @Романыч, это наверное единственный вариант, который возможно будет работать

Comment: @Романыч, основная цель сделать отдельный класс со своей логикой и пусть он управляет своими задачами, не нагружая кодом активность.

Comment: Сейчас пришло в голову сделать класс как Fragment, но без View. В onCreate добавить setHasOptionsMenu(true); и перекрыть onOptionsItemSelected. Как такая идея? Весь геморрой с подключением фрагмента можно вынести в конструктор... вроде.

Comment: @PawelShi, посмотрите пожалуйста мой ответ, может чем-то поможет :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря вы хотите что-то странное и не очень понятное. Логика использования тулбара такова:

1. Добавляем тулбар в xml:

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           android:visibility="gone" />
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
   ```
2. Делаем ресурс меню (пункты могут быть и другими):

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_delete"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
       android:title="@string/delete_mess"
       app:showAsAction="never" />

   <item
       android:id="@+id/edit"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
       android:title="@string/edit"
       app:showAsAction="never" />
   ```
3. Подключаем тулбар и обработчик нажатий на пункты в активности:

   ```
   override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
           inflater!!.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

           menu.findItem(R.id.write_message).setOnMenuItemClickListener {

               true
           }
       }
   }
   ```

и все. Вы же хотите каким-то магическим образом мало того что передать тулбар в левый класс, так еще и обработать там нажатие. Мое личное (можно критиковать если что) мнение - вы не сможете сделать так как хотите. Есть несколько причин почему не получится:

1. Без наследования класса активности вы не сможете получить доступ к методу `onOptionsItemSelected` а это значит что о нажатиях можно будет забыть.
2. Даже если вы сможете передать контекст в класс (это вполне реально сделать) вам все-равно нужно будет как-то дать программе понять что вы нажимаете кнопку (как уже сказал @Романыч можно использовать MVP).
3. Так как тулбар находится в разметке определенное активности вам нужно дать понять программе что вы находитесь в определенной активности а это будет довольно сложновато.

Единственный вариант - попробовать с MVP, [вот](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/493-mvp-dlja-nachinajuschih-bez-bibliotek-i-interfejsov.html) туториал есть по этой теме. Но тулбар принадлежит только активности и только активность сможет более-менее адекватно обработать все действия с тулбаром. Если же у вас задача сложная и требует этих трудозатрат то можно попробовать с mvp поиграть, в противном случае это все будет не нужно. Суть моего ответа не в том чтобы отговорить вас от попыток сделать то что вы хотите, идея интересна сама по себе, но без наследования класса вы не получите доступа к методам которые нужны для работы с вью элементами (например `onCreate()`).

Comment: Логику работы тулбара понимаю. Цель отдельного класса - минимизировать код в активности и перенести специфические функции в отдельный объект. У меня вопрос по MVP - для данной задачи перенести все управление логикой в Presenter?

Comment: смотрите в чем логика - вынести отдельные функции в класс, это можно и желание вполне нормальное (почитайте про синглтоны и все будет гуд) но использовать части активности без класса-активности это провал, сразу с первых минут, у активности не может быть только грубо говоря одна строка, нужно прописать логику работы и по-другому никак, да вы можете использовать какие-то ухищрения и плюшки но оооочень сильно минимизировать код вы не сможете, приложение же должно как-то работать и что-то делать кроме запуска :)

Comment: Хмм... без класса активности само собой и не планировал. Например в методе onCreate активности создавать объект класса, в конструктор передать саму активность и тулбар активности. А объект уже добавит туда кнопки. Идея была использовать этот класс в разных активностях и не городить зоопарк с наследование.

Comment: на мой взгляд это `в конструктор передать саму активность и тулбар активности` звучит как хардкорная фантастика)))) вот например в синглтоне вы сможете создать метод который например будет получать два числа а возвращать их сумму, и вы этот метод сможете использовать везде где будет экземпляр этого класса, но в отдельный класс передать активность это сложновато, и вероятнее всего даже если и получится (в чем я очень сильно сомневаюсь) то шкурка не стоит вычинки

Comment: каждая активность использует одинаковые методы которые созданы для работы с вью элементами, можно попробовать использовать разные плюшки для оптимизации кода, но это будет только текст и символы, сама суть будет одна и та же

Comment: Ну вот есть класс Adapter. При создании объекта данного класса мы передаем активность и View, с которой должен работать адаптер. Это же нормально. Адаптер преобразует данные для конкретного View. У меня похожая логика. Есть какие-то данные, для управления ими мне нужно вывести 2 кнопки на тулбар.

Comment: а почему нельзя просто использовать стандартный подход?) там кода не так уж и много)

Comment: Можно. Я его и использую. Возникло желание оптимизировать. Подобное нужно использовать в другой активности и захотелось не копировать код, а вынести в отдельный функционал